# Update dplyr filter per row

Tags: r, dplyr

Imagine I have the following data:

```
structure(list(A = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
), B = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 20, 5, 1, 2, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)), row.names = c(NA, 
-14L), class = "data.frame")
```

I now wish to remove all rows where B does not have an increment of 1, with the exception of when column A starts a new series.
I attempted to do this using `dplyr` via:

```
filter(df, (diff(append(B,NA,after=0))==1 | B==1))
```

Note that I append because the vector after `diff()` is 1 shorter than the original data.
This results in:

```
structure(list(A = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), B = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

The problem is that because I use `diff()` in order to determine whether the increment for column B is always 1, once an error in the data occurs, it will also (wrongfully) see the line after the error as wrong.
Is there a way to either:

- Circumvent this problem by using a more logical approach?
- Or would it be possible to make it so that the filter updates once it removes a row, so that the logic for diff() is correct. Though I imagine this will significantly slow the command down if it is even possible.

Comment: why do use strcture to create data frame, why not use a tibble like `tibble(
    A = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2),
    B = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 20, 5, 1, 2, 6, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7))`

Comment: That is indeed a bit easier, thanks! I was not quite sure how to generate clear fake data so made it by hand in R and then used dput. Thanks for the recommendation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work:

```
> library(dplyr)
> dat %>% group_by(A) %>% mutate(C = case_when(B - lag(B) != 1 & B - lag(B, n = 2) == 1 ~ 0, TRUE ~ 1)) %>%
+   mutate(C = lead(C, default = 1)) %>% filter(C == 1)
# A tibble: 12 x 3
# Groups:   A [2]
       A     B     C
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     1
 2     1     2     1
 3     1     3     1
 4     1     4     1
 5     1     5     1
 6     2     1     1
 7     2     2     1
 8     2     3     1
 9     2     4     1
10     2     5     1
11     2     6     1
12     2     7     1
>
```

Comment: not as elegant as yours but it does the job too.

`dat %>%
  group_by(A) %>%
  mutate(
    lag1_dff = B - lag(B, n = 1),
    lag2_diff = B - lag(B, n = 2)
    ) %>% 
  filter(lag1_dff == 1 | lag2_diff == 1 | is.na(lag1_dff)) %>%  # is.na to capture the first value in B
  select(A, B)`

Comment: @Karthik S It does the job indeed! This will certainly work for my current data, thank you! For future reference, would it be possible to automatically extend the `lag(B, n = 2)` part so that even if there are many wrong observations in a row this is still corrected for? Or would this have to be done manually? (e.g. `lag(B, n = 3 )` etc.)

Comment: "n" value in lag function represents how many rows you want to look behind, so you can change the numbers depending on your data.